# C code parser using else-if

Tags: c, regex, parsing

For the below [question](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node8.html#SECTION00840000000000000000),

> Exercise 12347 - Write a program which will read in the source of a C program from its standard input, and print out all the starred items in the following statistics for the program (all as integers). (Note the comment on tab characters at the end of this specification.)
>
> Print out the following values:
>
> ```
>   Lines:
>   *  The total number of lines
>   *  The total number of blank lines
>     (Any lines consisting entirely of white space should be
>     considered as blank lines.)
>     * The percentage of blank lines (100 * blank_lines / lines)
>
>   Characters:
>      *  The total number of characters after tab expansion
>      *  The total number of spaces after tab expansion
>      *  The total number of leading spaces after tab expansion
>      (These are the spaces at the start of a line, before any visible
>     character; ignore them if there are no visible characters.)
>     * The average number of characters per line
>     * characters per line ignoring leading spaces
>     * leading spaces per line
>     * spaces per line ignoring leading spaces
>
>   Comments:
>     *  The total number of comments in the program
>     *  The total number of characters in the comments in the program
>         excluding the "/*" and "*/" thenselves
>     * The percentage of number of comments to total lines
>     * The percentage of characters in comments to characters
>
> Identifiers:
>    * We are concerned with all the occurrences of "identifiers" in the
>      program where each part of the text starting with a letter,
>      and continuing with letter, digits and underscores is considered
>       to be an identifier, provided that it is not in a comment, or in a string, or within primes.
>     Note that "abc\"def"
>     the internal escaped quote does not close the string.
>     Also, the representation of the escape character is '\\'
>       and of prime is '\''
>   Do not attempt to exclude the fixed words of the language,
>   treat them as identifiers. Print
> *  The total number of identifier occurrences.
> *  The total number of characters in them.
> *   The average identifier length.
>
>   Indenting:
>    *  The total number of times either of the following occurs:
>       a line containing a "}" is more indented than the preceding line
>       a line is preceded by a line containing a "{" and is less
>       indented than it.
>       The "{" and "}" must be ignored if in a comment or string or
>       primes, or if the other line involved is entirely comment.
>    * A single count of the sum of both types of error is required.
>   NOTE: All tab characters ('') on input should be interpreted as multiple spaces using the rule:
>     "move to the next modulo 8 column"
>      where the first column is numbered column 0.
>
>   col before tab | col after tab
>         ---------------+--------------
>                 0      |      8
>                 1      |      8
>                 7      |      8
>                 8      |     16
>                 9      |     16
>                15      |     16
>                16      |     24
>     To read input a character at a time the skeleton has code incorporated to read a line at a time for you using
>    char ch;
>    ch = getchar();
>    Which will deliver each character exactly as read. The "getline" function then puts the line just read in the global array of characters "linec", null terminated, and delivers the length of the line, or a negative value if end of data has been encountered.
>    You can then look at the characters just read with (for example)
>
>    switch( linec[0] ) {
>     case ' ': /* space ..... */
>             break;
>     case '\t': /* tab character .... */
>             break;
>     case '\n': /* newline ... */
>             break;
>     ....
>     } /* end switch */
>   End of data is indicated by scanf NOT delivering the value 1.
>
>     Your output should be in the following style:
>
>    Total lines                     126
>     Total blank lines               3
>     Total characters                3897
>     Total spaces                    1844
>     Total leading spaces            1180
>     Total comments                  7
>     Total chars in comments         234
>     Total number of identifiers     132
>     Total length of identifiers     606
>     Total indenting errors          2
> You may gather that the above program (together with the unstarred items) forms the basis of part of your marking system! Do the easy bits first, and leave it at that if some aspects worry you. Come back to me if you think my solution (or the specification) is wrong! That is quite possible!
> ```

---

Here is my incomplete solution:

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef int bool;
#define true 1;
#define false 0;

int main(void){
    int ch;
    int numOfLines = 0;
    int numOfBlankLines = 0;
    int numOfCharAfterTab = 0;
    int numOfSpacesAfterTab = 0;

    bool isTabNow = false;
    bool isNewLine = false;
    bool isSpace = false;
    bool isChar = false;

    while(ch = getchar(), ch >= 0){

        if(ch == '\t')
        {
            isTabNow = true;
        }
        else if(ch == ' ')
        {
            if(isTabNow) 
            { 
                numOfSpacesAfterTab++; continue; 
            }  /* 4. Number of spaces after tab expansion*/
        }
        else if(ch == '\n')
        {
            isTabNow = false;
            numOfLines++;                         /* 1. Total number of Lines*/
            if(!isChar) 
            {
                numOfBlankLines++;
            }        /* 2. Total number of blank lines*/
        }
        else if((ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 0 && ch <= 9)||
                (ch >= '!' && ch <= '/') || (ch >= ':' && ch <= '@')||
                /* Referred ascii chart and compared 'ch' with ascii values of printable characters*/
                (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') || (ch >= '[' && ch <= '`') ||
                (ch >= '{' && ch <= '~'))
        {
            isChar=true;
            if(isTabNow){                          /* 3. Total number of characters after tab expansion*/
                numOfCharAfterTab++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n Invaid character %c", ch);
        }

    }// end while
}
```

---

Question:

Above problem recommended to use `switch-case`, but range of values could not be managed, unlike `else-if` syntax.

As per the above solution, I could not solve *total number of characters after tab expansion*. How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: You can't express value ranges with switch-case but you can either give all the values or preprocess `ch` so that the result expresses range of values: `if(ch>='a' && ch<='z') category=C_LOW;` with C_LOW defined somewhere else.

Comment: `(ch >= 0 && ch <= 9)` will disappoint you...

Comment: @ThomasAyoub why would it disappoint? Am comparing `ch` value if greater than equal to `0` and less than or equal to `9`

Comment: But `0 != '0'` :-)

Comment: @ThomasAyoub  `ch` is `int` type, so `ch` with value 1 is  `00000001`(assume 8 bit) so where is `'0'` in the condition?

Comment: `'0' == 048` see [asciitable](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: @ThomasAyoub but am not having `'0'`, it is `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put a *switch*, there is a half-way and full-way. The half-way is where you `switch` the one-char selection, then in *default* include the `if` tests for the rest

```
switch( ch ) {
  case '\t' : ...
  case '\n' : ...
  case ' ':  ...
  default: 
      if (isdigit(ch)) ....
      else ....
}
```

In the full-way, we define a table of all relevant characters and indicate what it is. An *enum* is used for readability.

The table is built once, before processing the file.

Making the table (`NONE` is set to 0 for clarity)

```
typedef enum { NONE=0, CR, TAB, LETTER, DIGIT, QUOTE, DQUOTE /* ... */ } Kind;

Kind table[256] = { NONE }; // default is invalid

int c;
table[ '\t' ] = TAB;
table[ '\n' ] = CR;
for(c='a' ; c<='z' ; c++) table[ c ] = LETTER;
/* ... */
```

Then in the program

```
switch(table[ ch ]) {
   case TAB: ....
   case LETTER: ....
   case ...
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir!!! Array looks more readable

Comment: So, `Kind` has to address with all ASCII chart printable characters. Correct?

Comment: Basically, anything you meet in the C file has to be covered, even invalid characters (eg the ones above 127). *Kind* defaults [actually *set*] to NONE. See [what is an enum](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/enum).

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the "effective column", that is the column where the editor would display the next character.

Rules:

1. The effective column starts at 0 and is increased by 1 for each character except tab and newline.
2. For a newline the effective column is reset to 0.
3. For a tab the effective column is increased by 1 and then "rounded" up to the nearest number divisible by 8. The intermediate characters are considered to be added space characters.

You need to keep track of how many spaces that where added due to the "round up to the nearest number divisible by 8" (=tab expansion) rule.

Comment: Ideally how many hours does it take to provide such solution? for a beginner?

Comment: @overexchange I'd say 20 minutes to add it to an existing solution (for an exercise). For a beginner probably 1-2 hours. But such things vary, if you get stuck with a bug and cannot figure out where you went wrong it could take longer, especially if you don't have a lab partner or tutor to discuss the problem with.